# Use eager loading sequelize with relational database without relationships

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm have a relational database (Postgres) that no has explicts relationships, i.e. foreign keys. 
But I'm using the Sequelize to consult data on database and I'd like to consult data with eager loading of Sequelize.

**Models**

*supplier*

```
const Supplier = sequelize.define(
    'Supplier',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      deleted: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
        field: 'excluido',
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        field: 'datacriacao',
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        field: 'dataalteracao',
      },
      socialName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'razaosocial',
      },
      logo: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'logo',
      },
    },
    {
      underscored: true,
      freezeTableName: true,
      timestamps: false,
      tableName: 'fornecedor',
    },
  );
```

*supplierAddress:*

```
const SupplierAddress = sequelize.define(
    'SupplierAddress',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        field: 'datacriacao',
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        field: 'dataalteracao',
      },
      address: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'endereco',
      },
      supplierId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'idfornecedor',
      },
    },
    {
      underscored: true,
      freezeTableName: true,
      timestamps: false,
      tableName: 'enderecofornecedor',
    },
  );
```

And I expected results that can obtained with:

```
SELECT * FROM supplier AS s INNER JOIN supplierAddress AS sa ON s.id = sa.supplierId;
```

How use the eager loading to do this consult? I'm new in the Sequelize.

I tried something like this, but not work:

```
static async getSuppliers() {
    try {
      database.Supplier.hasMany(database.SupplierAddress, {
        foreignKey: 'supplierId'
      });
      database.SupplierAddress.belongsTo(database.Supplier);
      const result = await database.Supplier.findAll({ include: database.SupplierAddress});
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));

      const list = await Promise.all(result);
      return list;
    } catch (error) {
      error.location =
        ' Exception raised by getSuppliersin SupplierService. ';
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const supplierModels = await database.Supplier.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: database.SupplierAddress,
    // this option is for INNER JOIN
    required: true
  }
});
const plainSupplierObjects = supplierModels.map(x => x.get({ plain: true })
console.log(JSON.stringify(plainSupplierObjects, null, 2));

// you don't need this line because you already got all Supplier records asynchronously.
//const list = await Promise.all(result);
return plainSupplierObjects;
```

Also you don't need to define associations every time before getting results. Just do this once right after registering your models in the sequelize.

Comment: How I'd define the associations?

Comment: Just move belongsTo and hasMany calls In your database js-file where you have all models.

Answer (score 0):

You don't must to define relation each time you use the model, you must to associate models after define both. A common solution is to use a static method `associate` who receive all models and do associations there.

Whatever, if your goal is not to have constraints relations, and keep it only on logical layer, you can use the option `constraints` in the association definition[0], like:

```
database.SupplierAddress.belongsTo(database.Supplier, {
    as: 'Suppliers',
    foreignKey: 'supplierId',
    constraints: false,
});
```

**Added:**

To find results, in this case you can do it:

```
database.SupplierAddress.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: database.Supplier,
        as: 'Suppliers',
    }]
});
```

But I recommend to create a new scope[1]:

```
database.SupplierAddress.addScope('withsuppliers', {
    include: [{
        models: database.Supplier,
        as: 'Suppliers',
    }],
});
```

And use then:

```
database.SupplierAddress.scope('withsuppliers').findAll();
```

0: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/constraints-and-circularities.html
1: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html